# How to return a value inside a function to another function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

so far I had no more problems and thought I could handle AngularJS a bit.
But now I tried to return a value without any results.
The third line calls my function to fetch a name from the database. But that function doesn't return the result.

```
$scope.showModal = function ($event,listId) {
    console.log("showModal: "+$event.type+" - id: "+listId);
    console.log("scope.listname: "+getListname(listId));
    $('#edit').modal('toggle');
};

function getListname(listId) {
    var query = 'SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)';
    $scope.db.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(query, [listId],
                function (tx, results) {
                    // console.log("Result: "+results.rows.item(0).name); // works!
                    return results.rows.item(0).name; // returns nothing or not to the sender
                }                      
            );
        }
    );
}
```

If I use console.log() within executeSql I get a value in the console. But why can't I get my result back to the calling function?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getListname(listId) {
     var query = 'SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)';
     var deferred = $q.defer();
     transaction.executeSql(query, [listId],
            function (tx, results) {
                 deferred.resolve(results.rows.item(0).name);
            }                      
     );
     return deferred.promise;
  }
```

Can use like this

```
 getListname(listId).then(function(name){
     $scope.db.transaction = name;
 });
```

Comment: Finally! Thank you ... it works!  
I just had to change $scope.db.transaction to $scope.listname.  
My problem was that I tried that deferred but as result I got an object [then, catch, finally] and didn't know what to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

Welcome to the world of async! `executeSql` is async so use a callback to access the data once that function completes:

```
function getListname(listId, callback) {
    var query = 'SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)';
    $scope.db.transaction(
      function (transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql(query, [listId],
            function (tx, results) {
                // console.log("Result: "+results.rows.item(0).name); // works!
                callback(results.rows.item(0).name); // returns nothing or not to the sender
            }                      
        );
    }
);
```

And then call it!

```
getListName(listId, function(name) {
    console.log(name);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use promise in order to write the code in sync way but execute it in async.
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q

Comment: Uh ... I tried to avoid that promise. In the past I had always problems with that because I don't really understand how to use it or how to implement it e.g. to my queries. :-(

Comment: @Tipo: Well, good time to learn more about it :) http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/es6/promises/

Comment: Thank you for that link. I will look after it.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is asynchronous, so you should handle it with callback:

```
function getListname(listId, callback) {
    var query = 'SELECT name FROM Lists WHERE id=(?)';
    $scope.db.transaction(
        function (transaction) {
            transaction.executeSql(query, [listId],
                function (tx, results) {
                // console.log("Result: "+results.rows.item(0).name); // works!
                    callback(results.rows.item(0).name); // returns nothing or not to the sender
                }                      
            );
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I got an error. I guess the "callback" is an unknown function.  
  The error is: `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

Comment: you shall pass callback function as a parameter to getListname like this: getListName(listId, function(name){ you have name variable here });

Comment: @Tipo the second function that you pass, will be called when database query operation will be completed

Comment: Hm, let me try what I think you will tell me here:  `console.log("scope.listname: "+getListname(listId, function (listname) {$scope.listname = listname;}));`  
Ok this don't show me an error but it also don't show me a result.  
I guess that I don't understand what you mean. I'm really really sorry. :-(